# What are some obscure/rare/endangered/extinct typographic symbols?

Tags: typography, symbols, history, glyphs

Just discovered the "asterism" today:

## ⁂

Super cool. I had never heard of it or seen it before. [Wikipedia has more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_%28typography%29).

What other typographic symbols are out there that were never all that popular or have fallen out of favor? What were they used for?

I placed in two that I know as a community wiki; I encourage others to build out a list.

Comment: pouring over unicode tables will reveal a cornucopia of hidden type symbols, virtually most of which i didn't know existed, let alone we could use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_%28typography%29)** `⁂` 
(Unicode character `U+2042` and HTML symbol `&#8258;` as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `8258` on Windows)

> Used to 'indicate minor breaks in text,' call attention to a passage, or to separate sub-chapters in a book.

---

**[Currency Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29)** `¤` 
(Unicode character `U+00A4` and HTML symbol `&#164;` or `&curren;` as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0164` on Windows)

> Used to denote a currency when the symbol for the particular currency is unavailable.

---

**[Interrobang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang)** `‽` 
(Unicode character `U+203D` and HTML symbol `&#8253;` as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `8253` on Windows)

> Used in various written languages and intended to combine the functions of the question mark … and the exclamation mark.

---

**[Sound Recording Copyright Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_recording_copyright_symbol)** `℗` 
(Unicode character `U+2117` and HTML symbol `&#8471;`)

> The copyright symbol used to provide notice of copyright in a sound recording (phonogram) embodied in a phonorecord (LPs, audiotapes, cassettes, compact discs, etc.)

---

**[Commercial Minus Sign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68999/5489)** `⁒` 
(Unicode character `U+2052` and HTML symbol `&#x2052;`)

> The commercial minus sign was and is widely used in bookkeeping to indicate a minus sign. On typewriters a `./.` was written instead.

---

*to be continued …* ;)

Comment: I want to know where you found those on your keyboard.

Comment: I don't think "interrobang" is nearly extinct.  I would expect the usage of "?!" or "!?" to be quite common, and, until now, considered the pair of glyphs as the *intended* meaning of the word instead of just a  *typographical representation*.   Now, the actual interrobang glyph "‽" as explained by Wikipedia... certainly rare.  Neither of them I'd say would be "going extinct", as I don't expect the usage of Unicode standards to stop anytime soon.

Comment: @JayC - I've never seen the interrobang glyph in the wild before. And if you read into it, it was never really mainstream anyways, but certainly an interesting footnote to typographic history :)

Comment: @LaurenIpsum `Ctrl` + `C` :P

Comment: *::rimshot::* No seriously... did you just copy them from the Wiki page, or is there some mysterious Vulcan nerve pinch you do on the keyboard to generate them?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Just copied them. But there might be Unicode shortcuts for them...I didn't check.

Comment: Interrobang is unicode x203D (8253 in base10). As to how you get them, it depends on OS. In windows, you hold alt key down and type the 4 digit decimal code on numpad, then release the alt key. The typeface must have the glyph, but since it is OS based, the technique is generally software agnostic. Note that unicode can cause issues with non-unicode aware/capable programs. In that case the best case is an ugly or missing character. (for other OS, see http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes )